# Using VBA to search for a text string in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA in a macro to search for a text string and delete the contents of the column. I previously found this on the website and would like to change it to search columns and delete the text "QA1" while retaining the columns.  I hope this makes sense.

```
LastRow = Cells(Columns.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
   If Range("D" & i).Value = "D" Then
      Range("D" & i).EntireColumn.Delete
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Have you tried out any modifications to the example code? What do you think each line is doing?

Answer (score 1):

You want to clear the contents of the whole column if one cell contains `QA1`?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(4)
        Set rCell = .Find("QA1", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            .ClearContents
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

If you want to just clear each instance of `QA1` in column D:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(4)
        Set rCell = .Find("QA1", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            Do
                rCell.ClearContents
                Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
            Loop While Not rCell Is Nothing
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

> Can it be written to look through the entire worksheet and delete QA1
>   where ever it is found?

All instances of `QA1` on sheet:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells
        Set rCell = .Find("QA1", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
            Do
                rCell.ClearContents
                Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
            Loop While Not rCell Is Nothing
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

**Edit:**  Add `LookAt:=xlWhole` to the `Find` arguments so it doesn't delete cells containing QA1 and other text (e.g. `QA11` or `Some text QA1`)

Comment: Thank you, this was what I was looking for.  I'm still in the process of learning VBA and macros so this is very appreciated.  Now to decipher what you wrote.  Thanks again.

Comment: I'd suggest checking these links:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx ,  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx  Feel free to mark as accepted answer if it is.

Answer (score 0):

This code goes through columns in a specified row and removes the "QA1" if found

```
Dim LastColumn As Integer
Dim RowNumber As Integer
Dim i As Integer

LastColumn = UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
RowNumber = 1 'Adjust to your needs

For i = 1 To LastColumn Step 1

      Cells(RowNumber, i).Value = Replace(Cells(RowNumber, i).Value, "QA1", "")
Next i
```

Comment: Can it be written to look through the entire worksheet and delete QA1 where ever it is found?

Comment: see jcarroll's answer

Answer (score 0):

Loops through the used range of the active worksheet, and removes the selected text.

```
Sub RemoveText()

    Dim c As Range
    Dim removeStr As String

    removeStr = InputBox("Please enter the text to remove")

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If c.Value = removeStr Then c.Delete
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked but since I have a lot of rows and columns it took a great deal of time for Excel to execute.  I plan to keep it all the same for future use.  Thank you.